# Problem with saving the record on the before insert trigger! Help!

Tags: apex, before-trigger

So, I have field called name on my custom field and I am writing a before trigger insert trigger to copy the name of the other lookup field into the name field which is a standard required field and looks like I cannot remove the required on the field. Now, my trigger copies the name of the other field into the name field only if I write something before saving. If I don't fill the name and try to save the record I get the error 'The following field must be completed : name' . How do I solve this because I cannot ask users to fill some rubbish as the name and tell them not to worry cause once they save the field the contents of the other field get copied ? Which is not bright I suppose.

```
if(Trigger.isBefore){
            //Process before insert that is to copy the name of the Template Id into the name of the checklist object
            set<Id>CheckListTemplateId = new set<Id>();
            for(CheckList__c c : Trigger.new){
                if(c.TemplateId__c != null){
                    CheckListTemplateId.add(c.TemplateId__c);  
                }   
            }
            System.debug('The set value is :' + CheckListTemplateId);
            if(!CheckListTemplateId.isEmpty()){
                Map<Id,CheckListTemplate__c> checkListTemplateObj = new Map<Id,CheckListTemplate__c>([Select Id, Name From CheckListTemplate__c Where Id IN: CheckListTemplateId]);
                for(CheckList__c c : Trigger.New){
                    if(checkListTemplateObj.get(c.TemplateId__c).name != null){
                        // Copy the value of Template name from CheckListTemplate__c into name in CheckList__c
                        c.Name = checkListTemplateObj.get(c.TemplateId__c).name;
                    }    
                }
            }        
        }
```

Comment: Some person made this question as duplicate, I am seeking some help from community. Is this question still visible ?

Comment: I closed your question because it appeared to me to be identical to your previous question and had the same answer: you can't do that with a trigger, but you can do it with other functionality, including a Quick Action. If I have misread your intent, I welcome clarification.

Comment: I still did not grasp what you meant by including a Quick Action. Could you eloborate and do you think creating a new name field will solve my problem ?

Comment: Two things. One, I will expand my answer on your previous question. Two, if you would like to edit *this* question to re-frame it so that it is not a duplicate, it can be reopened. If you wish to do so, please include a detailed description of your entire use case so that the community can assist you. (See [ask] for more).